# How do you read the performance tab in the Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, streamlit

I am building a webapp using python & streamlit - and performance is fine, but far from perfect.

I tried running the chrome developer "performance" but I don't know how to read the outputs.

Any idea?

[image]

To clarify, I'm not expecting an interpretation of this screenshot - just an explanation of how to read it.

Comment: Start with the `bottom-up` panel at the bottom to find the slowest code. The flame chart on your screenshot shows what happens over time, it's clickable so when some block is selected the bottom-up panel shows what happened inside. Anyway you really should read a tutorial on perf profiling in devtools to use it efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check some tutorials.